# How to go back to main view after opening dialog?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html pages application and on second page I open dialog by using `css` only.

1st page has one button:

```
<button onClick="redirectToDetails()">Go to details</button>
```

and JS:

```
function redirectToDetails(){
  window.location = "second-page.html";
}
```

---

on second page I have button `Back` and button 'open dialog'

JS:

```
function goBack(){
    window.history.back();
}

function openDialog(){
    window.location = "#modal-one"
}
```

[THE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ez2Ww81LJ1RvSgHlOgvY?p=preview)

My dialog content is:

```
<div class="gl-modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="gl-modal-dialog">
        <div class="gl-modal-header">
            <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
            <a href="#close" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gl-modal-footer">
            <a href="#close" class="btn">Nice!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**The problem:**

When I go from 1st view to second view and open Dialog, back button doesn't work. It opens me dialog again because I use `window.history.back();`

I tried a lot of ways to clear history, to redirect back to main page - **nothing works**

How can i open dialog and do not record to history , so `window.history.back();` will turn me to main view?

Can someone help me with that problem?

Comment: Just set the location back to the first page instead of using history.back ? Why would you use the history if it isn't what you need.

Comment: @Shilly it doesn't work, tried ` window.location = 'index.html';`. Please change my demo to test your approach. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? You could just open the modal (drop in on the front of the page) without changing the location, and then close it by hiding.

Comment: Since the modal is a hash fragment, ahve you tried window.location.hash = '#modal' instead?

Comment: @BartK well, I need to open dialog by using css only. If you can open dialog without redirect to `#modal-one` - try it but its other question. Right now I try to resolve above mentioned problem.Thanks

Comment: You could try fiddling with `window.history.go(-2)` instead of .back() to go back two steps, but then you's have to save that number in a avr and update it every time the modal gets opened. That would fix the issue. But it wouldn't solve that it's just less-optimal design. In this specific case, just a hyperlinks would suffice, no need for buttons with click handlers etc. For the record, you use js to open the modal, not css. If it was css only, you'd have like a :hover or so open the modal.

Comment: @Shilly tried `window.history.go(-2)` and it doesn't work too. Try to put it in my demo.Thanks

Comment: you can do one thing, declare one function for closing dialog and use there same function for history.back and by that way only you can achieve this

Comment: conditional `window.history.go(-3)` will make it but only if the dialog has been opened once [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yshg3dF95ekTCyrodqh5?p=preview) , if it could be triggered more than one time it wouldn't work

Comment: @Vickyexpert bingo!! Your solution works, at last, thank you. Good catch, you welcome to post your answer with this working solution demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1cDLA8hRw1sBIuM0PLBB?p=preview

Comment: Enjoy your coding

Comment: @Vickyexpert but for safari I should use `href="javascript:history.go(-1)"`

Comment: @snaggs I have changed your second html page and test in both firefox and safari and it is working fine so check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you should just stick to two technologies, not mix up hyperlinks and hashes and manual history manipulation. Use simple hyperlinks for navigation between views and use hash links for the modals. That way the standard browser back button even works as well.

This version works for me:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Main view</h1>
    <a href="second-page.html">Second view</a>
</body>
</html>
```

second-page.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html  >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Second view</h1>                       
  <a href="index.html">Back</a>
  <button  onClick="openDialog()" >open Dialog</button>  
  <div class="gl-modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="gl-modal-dialog">
        <div class="gl-modal-header">
            <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
            <a href="#close" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a> <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gl-modal-footer">
            <a href="#close" class="btn">Nice!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>       

    <script>
      function openDialog(){
        window.location.hash = "#modal-one"
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you change my demo with your example? I cannot make it work with your solution

Comment: @snaggs http://plnkr.co/edit/1xQyLoaQKs1TQeOI3xgQ?p=preview You can even change the button to open the modal to a hyperlink as well, no javascript needed, only hyperlinks and css. Hyperlinks as the engine of application state. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Declare one function as below,

```
    function closeDialog() {
  window.history.back();
}
```

**Now change your close tag as below**

```
 <a href="" onclick="closeDialog()" class="btn">Nice!</a>
```

**New Second Html File**

```
  <!doctype html>
 <html  >
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
   <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>

   <h1>Second view</h1>
 </br>


   <a  href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>
   </br>
   </br>
 </br>


 <button  onClick="openDialog()" >open Dialog</button>  


   <div class="gl-modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="gl-modal-dialog">
                 <div class="gl-modal-header">
                     <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
                     <a onClick="closeDialog()" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a> <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="gl-modal-footer">
                     <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn">Nice!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
                 </div>
             </div>



         </div>       




     <script>

       function openDialog(){
       window.location = "#modal-one"
       console.log(window.location);
     }
     </script>      

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Shelley's answer is more accurate, Thank you for efforts

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use checkbox to trigger the modal, thus you will not need to deal with the hash issue because it doesn't produce hash fragments, basically give both the checkbox `display:none`, style the `label` to look like a button.

Also the `label` must have `for` attribute to be tied to the corresponding checkbox even if there're other elements between them, it could wrap it too but using `for` gives you more freedom.

[**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4JoL6eONqueZW5vJYaKV?p=preview)

CSS:

```css
.chkbx, .overlay {
  /* hide all overlays and checkboxes */
  display: none;
}
#chk1:checked ~ #over1 {
  /*if checkbox#chk1 is checked, trigger the display of the div#over1 */
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<label class="btn-label" for="chk1">open modal - using label (css only)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" id="chk1">
<div class="overlay" id="over1">
  <div class="modal">this is modal
    <p><a href="#" class="close-btn" id="close1">close</a>
    and yes you can have another label to close the modal with no need for javascript
    <p><label class="btn-label" for="chk1">close</label></p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **`~`** in `#chk1:checked ~ #over1` will work only if overlay `#over1` comes *after* (but not necessary right after it, other elements could be between them) the checkbox `#chk1`, both are siblings and having same parent (you can use `chk1:checked + #over1` instead but then `#over1` *must come right after* `#chk1` with no elements between them)